# How to combine two classes that have same properties?

Tags: css

For example, if I have:

```
.logIn {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #151719;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 20px;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.signUp {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #151719;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 20px;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I repeat the same code twice, what is the correct syntax to combine them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separating the classes with a comma should do the trick.

```
.logIn, .signUp {
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #151719;
        color: white;
        margin: 0 20px;
        float: right;
        padding-top: 16px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```